# error on inserting data into mysql using python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database

my aim was to insert name, userID and password of user so i used this code.

```
os.system('cls')
nme = input("enter your name: ")
usid = input("enter your userID: ")
pasd = int(input("please enter a pin in digits, characters are not supported: "))
entry = """insert into users (name, ID, pin) values('nme', 'usid', 'pasd')"""
curs.execute(entry)
```

but in the line5, instead of value getting inserted from variables, the whole variable is getting recognised as data input. please help!!

Comment: I think you want `insert into users (name, ID, pin) values(%s, %s, %s)`, then pass values to `execute` as 2nd parameter.

Comment: @user3783243 
I couldn't understand those %s things. what are they used for and how would they take values from the variables

Comment: They are placeholders. The driver binds them. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: @user3783243 thanks, i understood!!!